# How can I improve the compatibility of this Javascript library?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I've been working on a Javascript library, one with basic functionality.

I'm fairly new to Javascript, and am weaning myself off of jQuery, mainly for the sake of self-improvement.

My goal is to have a javascript library compatible with IE 8+, so I'm looking for browser-specific gotchas.

One specific problem is my event module, which doesn't seem to work when I try to add multiple events to one selector in Firefox 4.

Here's the module in question:

And the rest of the library is at github:  https://github.com/timw4mail/kis-js/blob/master/kis.js

```js
 (function(){

    var attach, remove, add_remove, e;

    if(document.addEventListener)
    {
        attach = function(sel, event, callback)
        {
            if(sel.addEventListener)
            {
                sel.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
            }
        };

        remove = function(sel, event, callback)
        {
            if(sel.removeEventListener)
            {
                sel.removeEventListener(event, callback, false);
            }
        };  
    }
    else
    {
        attach = function(sel, event, callback)
        {
            if(sel.attachEvent)
            {
                sel.attachEvent("on"+event, callback);
            }
        };

        remove = function(sel, event, callback)
        {
            if(sel.detachEvent)
            {
                sel.detachEvent("on"+event, callback);
            }
        };
    }

    add_remove = function (sel, event, callback, add)
    {
        var i,len;

        if(!sel)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //Get the DOM object if you give me a selector string
        if(typeof sel === "string")
        {
            sel = $(sel);
        }

        //Multiple events? Run recursively!
        event = event.split(" ");

        if(event.length > 1)
        {
            console.log(event);

            len = event.length;

            for(i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                add_remove(sel, event[i], callback, add);
            }

            return;
        }

        //Check for multiple DOM objects
        if(sel.length > 1)
        {
            len = sel.length;
            for(i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                (add === true)
                    ? attach(sel[i], event, callback)
                    : remove(sel[i], event, callback);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            (add === true)
                ? attach(sel, event, callback)
                : remove(sel, event, callback);
        }
    };

    e = {
        add: function(sel, event, callback)
        {
            add_remove(sel, event, callback, true);
        },
        remove: function(sel, event, callback)
        {
            add_remove(sel, event, callback, false);
        }
    };

    window.$_.event = e;

 }());
```

Comment: Here, have a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NbDnX/1/

Comment: Thanks, I updated it to show the specific issue.

Comment: You updated the jsfiddle? I need a link to the new version to see it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. When you click `update` in jsfiddle, it gives you a new url. (I also accidentally upvoted the above comment, but there's no undo for upvoting comments)

Comment: Ahh...there we go http://jsfiddle.net/NbDnX/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a while of searching, I found the problem is not with your library at all, but is with your test code. The problem is that `innerText` doesn't work in Firefox 4. A version of [your test code](http://jsfiddle.net/NbDnX/6/), updated to use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`, works perfectly.

Also, your library has some other compatibility issues that I thought I should point out:

```
sel.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
```

and

```
sel.removeEventListener(event, callback, true);
```

should have matching parameters for their third argument.

Quote from [MDC wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener):

> If a listener was registered twice, one with capture and one without, each must be removed separately. Removal of a capturing listener does not affect a non-capturing version of the same listener, and vice versa.

And also, another compatibility thing (for IE8 or below): `attachEvent` expects you to have "on" before the event name, like so: `element.attachEvent("onmouseover", function(){...});`

Comment: That's helpful to know, although the issue I had was with attaching events. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the full source with those changes. Thanks for the input.

Comment: There you go, the problem was with `innerText` and not your code.

Comment: Well, that's definitely a good thing to know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have any other feedback on the library itself? https://github.com/timw4mail/kis-js/blob/master/kis.js

Comment: You could try asking for feedback about the library in the [javascript chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript), if you want. I think I might signup for Github and fork your project there as well.

Answer (score 0):

window.$*.event returns an error, did you mean widnow.$* = e, so that you can use

```
 $_.add(document.getElementById('test'), 'click', function(){ alert(1); });
```

(add and remove) outside of the function's scope?

Also, you will have to use different events for IE8 (in attachHandler), since instead of click you will have to write onclick, onfocus instead of focus, etc.

Comment: I think $_ is defined elsewhere in his library.

Comment: Yeah, I define the $_, and $ elsewhere. $ is a selector function, and $_ is the main library variable.